# accordion check box jquery and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a jquery accordion. Within the tab name I have a check box, but I am unable to check it.

Not sure why this is occurring. Does anyone know a way around this?

```
   <!--Start Bens New Accordion-->
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#accordion")
                .accordion({
                    collapsible: true,
                    active: false,
                    heightStyle: "content"
                });
        });
    </script>
    <!--End Bens New Accordion-->
</head>

<div id="accordion">
    <h3>
        <label for='product-44-44'>
            <input type='checkbox' id='product-44-44' name='product_id_page-0[44-44]' value='44-44'
                   data-first_price="11.99" data-second_price="" data-paysys=""/>
            BUNDLE PACK: Practise Every Type of Test
        </label>
    </h3>
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="d1">
            1 list
        </div>
        <div class="d2">
            2 list
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be much appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Possible z-index issue? Try setting the z-index on the checkbox to something ridiculous like 10000 and give it a position:relative

Comment: Thats a good idea, thanks +1

Comment: Issue resolved ??

Comment: It's because you have put the label into the header of the accordion.  The click event to open the accordion is in that header so it will stop propagation to other click events.  You either need to put the label and input into the content part, or extend the click action for the header to also then toggle the input

Comment: No, not a z index provlem

Comment: Thanks Pete, ill find a way around this. thanks you

Comment: @BenjaminOats, you could write extra functionality into the activate event: https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate

Comment: Nice, ill looking to this +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***UPDATED***

Your input field cannot receive the event because in the jQuery UI source code there is:

```
_eventHandler: function( event ) {
........
event.preventDefault();
```

This means that whenever you click the checkbox, the default event is inhibited.

So, as a workarount,  you can re-enable this event for the checkbox in order to execute the inhibited action (check/uncheck):

```js
$(function () {
  $("#accordion")
  .accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    heightStyle: "content"
  });


  $("#accordion").find('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.checked = !this.checked;
    }.bind(this), 100);
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="accordion">
    <h3>
        <label for='product-44-44'>
            <input type='checkbox' id='product-44-44' name='product_id_page-0[44-44]' value='44-44'
                   data-first_price="11.99" data-second_price="" data-paysys="" style="z-index: 100;"/>
            BUNDLE PACK: Practise Every Type of Test
        </label>
    </h3>

    <div class="columns">
        <div class="d1">
            1 list
        </div>
        <div class="d2">
            2 list
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My workarount is:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#accordion")
  .accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    heightStyle: "content",
    beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
    if(event.originalEvent.target.tagName == 'INPUT' && event.originalEvent.target.type.toLowerCase() == 'checkbox') {
        event.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function() {
          event.originalEvent.target.checked = !event.originalEvent.target.checked;
        }, 100);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="accordion">
    <h3>
        <label for='product-44-44'>
            <input type='checkbox' id='product-44-44' name='product_id_page-0[44-44]' value='44-44'
                   data-first_price="11.99" data-second_price="" data-paysys="" style="z-index: 100;"/>
            BUNDLE PACK: Practise Every Type of Test
        </label>
    </h3>
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="d1">
            1 list
        </div>
        <div class="d2">
            2 list
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm how would this work though if i had many tabs with difrent  IDs

Comment: @BenjaminOats Now it's completely generic. Let me know if it solve your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per my comments, the click is being disabled as the label is inside the header of the accordion, which has it's own event attached for opening the content div - this either has prevent default or stop propagation attached to it so stops your label action firing.

To get around this you can try the following:

```js
$("#accordion")
  .accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    heightStyle: "content",
    beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
      var oldInput = ui.oldHeader.find('input');
      oldInput.prop('checked', !oldInput.prop('checked')) // this bit unchecks when the accordion is closed

      var newInput = ui.newHeader.find('input'); // this bit checks when the accordion is opened
      newInput.prop('checked', !newInput.prop('checked'))
    }
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>
        <label for='product-44-44'>
            <input type='checkbox' id='product-44-44' name='product_id_page-0[44-44]' value='44-44'
                   data-first_price="11.99" data-second_price="" data-paysys=""/>
            BUNDLE PACK: Practise Every Type of Test
        </label>
    </h3>
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="d1">
      1 list
    </div>
    <div class="d2">
      2 list
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However this will make your checkboxes act like radios in that if you have multiple accordion sections, it will only check the checkbox for the open section

Comment: Hmm this looks good, i think i may have found a solution to this as well. ill implement them all and see what works best